# PHP, order an array of different objects by field

Tags: php, arrays, object

I need to order an array that has inside different objects. These object have a parameter in common. Example:

```
class One 
{
    private $value;
    [...methods...]
}


class Two 
{
    private $value;
    [...methods...]
}
```

I have an array of these objects and I've tried to order them using uasort in this way:

```
uasort ($array,
    function($val1, $val2) 
    {
        return ($val1 -> getValue()) < ($val2 -> getValue())
    });
```

But everytime I do this I get a "local" order, in the array there are in the first positions the objects of class One and then the objects of class two. Like:

```
One ($value = 10)
One ($value = 11)
One ($value = 14)
Two ($value = 9)
Two ($value = 14)
Two ($value = 19)
```

What I need is:

```
Two ($value = 9)
One ($value = 10)
One ($value = 11)
Two ($value = 14)
One ($value = 14)
Two ($value = 19)
```

I really can't get my head around this. Has anybody a solution for this problem?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The comparison function is supposed to return `-1`, `0`, or `1`, not `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uasort ($array,
    function($val1, $val2) 
    {
        $value1 = $val1->getValue();
        $value2 = $val2->getValue();
        if ($value1 < $value2) {
            return -1;
        } elseif ($value1 > $value2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code, but, unfortunately, the problem remains the same objects are not ordered, guess I'll check my code, again, to see if there are errors